# How to split up IP address in PHP

Tags: php, ip

I'm trying to split up a string (IP Address) to get each part of the ip address into separate variables.

E.g. 
$ip = "123.124.125.126"

I would like to get: $ip1 = "123", $ip2 = "124" separately, splitting up the variables using the period.

I'm obtaining the IP address using this code:

```
<?php
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

echo $ip;
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [explode](http://php.net/explode)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `explode` and `list`.

```
list($ip1, $ip2, $ip3, $ip4) = explode(".", "192.168.1.1");
```

Comment: While `list` is handy here, the really important part of your answer is the `explode` call. Saying "you can use list" is like saying "you can use a key" to answer "how can I get to the next city" instead of "you can use a car".

Comment: All languages (that I know of) have some kind of explode or split function, not  all of them have a `list` construct.

Comment: Sure, but the OP doesn't seem to have heard of `explode` even. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should really look at explode();

```
$ip_parts = explode (".", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

then get parts via

```
$ip_parts[0], $ip_parts[1]; //etc..
```

Explode splits string into array by first argument given to function in this case '.' in more advanced cases you can use preg_split, where you can provide regular expression.

If you want proper validation of IP you can also get IP parts by preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function that you are looking for is called explode()

Syntax:
explode(separator,string,limit)

```
<?php
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
?>
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)